# Android studio - back button doesn't return to the same page on every device

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator, back-button

So me and my group is making an app. We're working from home all of us, and are using different emulators. Problem is, when some of us are entering a new activity from a tab in a fragment, then presses back, they come to a different page than some of us. We're supposed to go to the same fragment as last time.

The weird thing is that it works fine for some of us, regardless of who has downloaded the project fresh from github or not. Anyone knows what is going on?

Note: We're having the back button in the toolbar, and the one integrated in androidOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Leaving it here for anyone else that might have the problem.
Apparently it's due to using android R, which supports the next android version (version 11), while i was using Q(version 10). Luckily i don't need R yet, as Q just released.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Android OS provided back-button, you can add a back button, maybe to the top-left of the screen. You can then create an intent to take the user back to the desired fragment/activity.

Comment: I do have that i believe. I got it declared in the Manifest where each back button should lead. That's why it's weird it leads different places for different people using the same emulators

Comment: No, I meant, go to your layout file and then add a button manually(activity_<activity name>.xml)

Answer (score 0):

back between activity and fragment:

fragment:

```
fragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
fragment.getView().requestFocus();
fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
           // code back 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} );
```